# How to "signal" to a windows process?

Tags: windows, signal

I need to signal to my daemon program to reload its configuration. I am a GNU/Linux developer and I usually use SIGHUP signal for this. What are the similar way to do this with program running on Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many programs seem to use [event objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) for this purpose (as well as occassional semaphore objects and mutex objects). All three types are persistent, OS-wide objects with a name and an ACL. The WinObj tool shows many Windows services using event objects to signal their own state to other tools, but there doesn't seem to be any reason preventing the opposite usage.

If you want to implement a more complete IPC between the daemon and a `*ctl`-like tool (which on Linux would typically be done via Unix sockets), the closest Windows equivalent might be "named pipes", which are actually bidirectional and really much more like Unix sockets than Unix pipes.